# android MultiAutoCompleteTextView detect suggestion list item click

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

In application i am using MultiAutoCompleteTextView for select contact from local database. I have to abort adding text in MultiAutoCompleteTextView while user click on Auto Suggestion List Item ?

Basically i don't want add same contact into MultiAutoCompleteTextView  if it already added.

Please help me ASAP.

Comment: You can use multiAutoCompTextview.setOnItemClickListener();